# Click only table header title

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

In my `table` if I click table header data will be sorted. There is checkbox in that header, when I click on header title that checkbox also clicking. I want only working the sort when I click on header title.

[image: my table]

This is the table header code.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php if ($folder_id && $sub_folders) { ?>
        <th width="2%"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="selected_check"></th>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?><?php } else { ?>
        <th width="5%"></th>
        <?php } ?>
        <th width="5%"></th>
        <th class="vf-icon"></th>
        <th ><?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/" . $folder_id . "/title"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/0/title"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } ?>Title</a></th>
        <th width="20%" class="text-center"><?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/" . $folder_id."/size"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/0/size"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } ?>Size</a></th>
        <th width="20%" class="text-center"><?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/" . $folder_id."/last_updated"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/0/last_updated"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } ?>Last Updated</a></th>
        <th width="20%" class="text-center"><?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/" . $folder_id."/created_by"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo base_url('files/browse') . "/0/created_by"; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php } ?>Created By</a></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: provide the sorting code or any code that may help solve your problem

Comment: @ madalin ivascu  Found the answer Thanks you effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is `Propagation`.
use this code in your jQuery function.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

read [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for your additional knowladge.
Cheers.

Comment: how can I use this?

Comment: @SunethSenanayake : You can simply add class to table header and write code in jQuery click event.Then you can use this.Understood ?

Comment: Great!! Good luck.